# ReactJS - If Object Has Length

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how I can use an if statement within my state component to determine if an element should be displayed based on if the object has values. Should logic exist in a separate prop component?

**The "If statement" I'm trying to use:**

```
if(props.files){
  return ( <button className={ this.state.fileLinksButtonClosed ? "record-footer__accordion-button record-footer__file-links-button--closed" : "record-footer__accordion-button record-footer__file-links-button--opened"} onClick={this.handleClick}>File Attachments ({this.props.files.length})</button>
} else {
  return null;
}
```

**Current component:**

```
//Record - Footer - File Link Accordion
class RecordFilesAccordion extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            fileLinksHidden: true,
            fileLinksButtonClosed: true
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(){
        this.setState({ 
            fileLinksHidden: !this.state.fileLinksHidden,
            fileLinksButtonClosed: !this.state.fileLinksButtonClosed
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="annotation-file">
                <button className={ this.state.fileLinksButtonClosed ? "record-footer__accordion-button record-footer__file-links-button--closed" : "record-footer__accordion-button record-footer__file-links-button--opened"} onClick={this.handleClick}>File Attachments ({this.props.files.length})</button>
                { this.state.fileLinksHidden ? null : <RecordFiles files={this.props.files}/> }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to check whether your object has any values or is empty you can use

```
if(Object.keys(props.files).length>0)
```

as the condition. This will be `true` if props.files is an array with at least 1 element or an object with at lease 1 field.

**EDIT** (after comment from @cphill): I think your render method should be

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div className="annotation-file">
               {Object.keys(props.files).length>0?
                <button className={ this.state.fileLinksButtonClosed ? "record-footer__accordion-button record-footer__file-links-button--closed" : "record-footer__accordion-button record-footer__file-links-button--opened"} onClick={this.handleClick}>File Attachments ({this.props.files.length})</button>
                : null}
                { this.state.fileLinksHidden ? null : <RecordFiles files={this.props.files}/> }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Since 0 is falsy you don't need to compare the length to 0.

Comment: @ShawnWhinnery Agree. But IMO this is more readable. Or it can be written as `if(!!Object.keys(props.files).length)`

Comment: Thanks @palsrealm, I feel like this would be the best solution, but do you know how to incorporate that in my component above? I currently have an error when I wrap the button in the render method because I try to return the button in `true` portion of my if statement

Comment: @cphill Updated the answer with code for the render method. Let me know if this works.